# Passing commands arguments in a variable

Tags: bash, nmap

So I have this peace of bash code to execute `nmap` command with different arguments in `$line` variable

When I transform it into an in-line command it works perfectly with separated arguments from `$line`, but in a script, it takes what's in `$line` as one argument

Not sure if it's an Nmap issue or a bash issue but since it worked in command line i believe it's a bash issue

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

```
function feedToNmap() {
        while read line
        do
                nmap $line >> nmap_out
        done < nmap_input
}
```

Comment: I assume you have copied the script code verbatim i.e. not omitted any use of quoting in the script or in `nmap_input`

Try `read -a line` and `nmap ${line[@]}`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do `nmap "$line" >> nmap_out`?

Comment: ... or perhaps you are using a different shell such as `zsh` in which unquoted variable expansions do not undergo word splitting by default?

Comment: change the field separator `IFS` and `read` delimiter `-d` into whitespace otherwise each line is one `$line` for `\n`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys, turned out to be a weird issue

I was adding to an array before this function with something like this:
`array <<< elements` (i dont remember the exact line)

Apparently the three `<<<` missed up the code that comes after for some reason, idk why but I worked it around by adding to the array without `<<<`

Comment: It would be better to quote your actual wrong code, and the corrected code, and then to say why the corrected code works while the wrong code does not.  You can't create an array with `<<<` directly.